# Implement an has_one polymorphic association with rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgis, polymorphic-associations, has-one

I'm working with spacial data with postgis.

I have a generic poi table with datas as name, address and longitude and latitudes

I'm working too with the friendly_id gem

I would like to have accomodations, catering and cities from a Poi.

One Poi has one accomodation or one catering or one city

I have a lot a functions that works for a Poi.

I would like to get the datas for each kind , by the poi.

I think I must build  a system with a has_one polymorphic association... but I don't know, what's the better way to do.

What's I would like to do  ?

To call a Poi with differents scopes (catering, accomodations, etc...) by friendly_id.

For exemple, i Would like to call

Poi.accomodation
Poi. cities
Poi.catering

And, for each one, to have a special rendering.

Any help is very welcome... I'm newbie on rails... and my english is not better :(

Poi model :

```
class Poi < ApplicationRecord
   extend FriendlyId
   friendly_id :name_and_zip_code, use: :slugged
   has_one :town, as: poitable
   has_one :accomodation, as poitable
```

Town model :

```
class Town < ApplicationRecord
 belongs_to :poitable

end
```

Catering model :

```
class Accomodation < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :poitable
end
```

But I have an error, Poi can't have the both.....

**Edit 1**

What I have do ?

```
class Poi < ApplicationRecord
   extend FriendlyId
   friendly_id :name_and_zip_code, use: :slugged
   geocoded_by :full_address
   has_one :town, as: :poitable
   has_one :accomodation, as: :poitable

class Accomodation < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :poitable, polymorphic: true

class Town < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :poitable, polymorphic: true
```

In db:migration :

```
class CreatePois < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
     create_table :pois do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.st_point :lonlat, geographic: true
      t.st_point :lonlatheight, geographic: true, has_z: true
      t.belongs_to :user, index: true
      t.references :poitable, polymorphic: true, index: true
    end
  end
end
```

db:migration Accomodations

```
class CreateAccomodations < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    create_table :accomodations do |t|
     t.string :genre
    end
  end
 end
```

db:migration Towns

```
class CreateTowns < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    create_table :towns do |t|
    t.string :department
   end
 end
end
```

In erb, I can create a Poi but :

- Poitable_id : nil
- Poitable_type : nil

But, I can't create a Town or an Accomodation... I have a rollback :(

How can I fix it ?

Answer (score 0):

I think your models should be like this:

Poi model:

```
class Poi < ApplicationRecord
  extend FriendlyId
  friendly_id :name_and_zip_code, use: :slugged
  has_one :town, as: :poitable
  has_one :accomodation, as: :poitable
```

Town model:

```
class Town < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :poitable, polymorphic: true
end
```

Catering model:

```
class Accomodation < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :poitable, polymorphic: true
end
```

P/S: For more information about associations. You can take a look at this [guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html)

Comment: Thanks for your help... I have read many guides, but they speak around has_many polymorphic association, not for has_one. I have updated my answer, if you could look ;)

Comment: Hi @Ben, I've created a sample project for your problem. Mine is working fine, perhaps you could take a look. https://github.com/AlecksJohannes/rails-polymorphism. Pay attention to the [db migration](https://github.com/AlecksJohannes/rails-polymorphism/tree/master/db/migrate) file. I think you missed two fields that are `poitable_id` and `poitable_type` in `Town` and `Accomodation` model. If that is true, you should run `rails g migration` and then add two missing fields like in my sample project.

Comment: I try it, and, yes it work... but It have no sens. All towns and all accomodations have the same poitable_type.
I think one poi have an accomodation or a town poitable_type. Maybe,  I need to create the towns or the accomodations before the poi. It's not really what I expeted :(

Comment: No, I think you should create `accomodation `and `town` based on current `poi` record. For instance `@poi = Poi.find(params[:id])`. And do `@poi.create_town` or `@poi.create_accomodation`, `@poi` is your current poi record. After create `accomodation` and `town`, you can do `@poi.town`, to see if it works.

Comment: BUT I cant create a poi, before à town.... Activerecord need to have poitable_id and poitable_type before end return an error 

Comment: Wait you have `poitable_id` and `poitable_type` in your `Poi` model?

Comment: Yes, because is more logic. But thanks for your help, I will try by another way ;) I don't think I was thinking the right way.

Comment: It shoudn't be, poitable_id and poitable_type should belongs to `Accomodation` and `Town`.

Comment: I did it and it work fine ;) It makes more sense to have different poitable_type in poi, rather than the same poitable_type in town and accomodation ;)